# How can I fix spellout in php

Tags: php, intl

Good day everyone. I have a problem regards on my code.
I'm trying to make a simple program that converts numbers into words but I've encountered some issue below is my code.

```
$num = 900.00;
$exp = explode('.', $num);
$f = new NumberFormatter("en_US", NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT);
$num_words = ucfirst($f->format($exp[0])) . ' point ' . ucfirst($f->format($exp[1]));
```

Im expecting an output of

> Nine hundread

And here's I got

> Nine hundred point Zero

And here's the error

> Notice: Undefined offset: 1

Can someone help me with this. Im struggling to find an answer. Thank you everyone

Comment: why u used `$num_words = ucfirst($f->format($exp[0])) . ' point ' . ucfirst($f->format($exp[1]));` ? why not just `$num_words = ucfirst($f->format($exp[0]));`

Comment: @Gagantous because I want to read the "cents" too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `if else` like this to check the number behind the point. If it's zero or less than 1, don't use `point` word

```
$num = floatval(900.00);
$exp = explode('.', $num);
$f = new NumberFormatter("en_US", NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT);
// check the number if the number behind point/comma is less than 1
if(count($exp) == 1){
    $num_words = ucfirst($f->format($exp[0]));
}else{
// other than that print with point
    $num_words = ucfirst($f->format($exp[0])) . ' point ' . ucfirst($f->format($exp[1]));
}
```